# Timing issues pushing and shifting Javascript arrays at the same time

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to 'push' incoming data to an array continuously while performing multiple 'shift' operations to do bulk writes to Elasticsearch every 3-5 seconds in a function.  I've seen plenty of documentation explaining these operations but nothing about the timing of them when performed simultaneously.  What happens if I try to 'push' and 'shift' at the same time?  Is there a better way of doing this?

I'm using Sitepoint and the links below for my information:

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp)

[Modern JavaScript Tutorial](https://javascript.info/array)

Comment: Array `push` and `shift`? They are synchronous, so it's one after the other.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve], especially the code with your actual results and the expected results.

Comment: How do you call `.push()` and `.shift()` at the same time? The function calls should not affect each other relevant to the resulting array

Comment: arr.push(arr.shift())

Comment: Please include **all relevant information in the body of the post**, so that the post remains relevant if the link goes down.  Also, it's much easier for fellow users to help if the concise is in one location.  It's fine to include the source links as additional reference.

Comment: JS is single-threaded, so as has been mentioned you *can't* do `push()` and `shift()` (or any other operations) "at the same time", even if you have two separate timer-based operations occurring. If you have two asynchronous processes adding and removing items from the same array I think the only thing you'd need to worry about is that the code that removes items needs to test whether the array is empty.

Comment: I really need to do them separately because the function to write to Elasticsearch will be on a timer to do bulk writes, since 1 bulk write of 1000 documents is faster than 1000 writes of individual documents.  Incoming data will be sporadic so it may not be worth writing the data to Elasticsearch continuously.  And, if I do get a spike of data, I'll run into issues performing individual writes to Elasticsearch.  These are phone log entries, so I would prefer to 'shift' the oldest array elements first, rather than popping the newest data and working my way backwards.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you answered my question nnnnnn.  It sounds like I just need to try the shift() until it completes without an error because the pushes won't always occur at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS is single-threaded, so as has been mentioned you can't do push() and shift() (or any other operations) "at the same time", even if you have two separate timer-based operations occurring. If you have two asynchronous processes adding and removing items from the same array I think the only thing you'd need to worry about is that the code that removes items needs to test whether the array is empty. – Provided by user 'nnnnnn'.

So, I need to 'try' the shift() and push() until they succeed without an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it together like this:

```
arr.push(arr.shift())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  But, I really need to do them separately because the function to write to Elasticsearch will be on a timer to do bulk writes, since 1 bulk write of 1000 documents is faster than 1000 writes of individual documents.